# i want to open pdf in new tab after button click but it work on local not on server

Tags: c#

I want to open a Pdf in new tab after click link button it is work fine in local but when i upload it in server it show me after some time connection reset here is my code....

```
enter code here ` try
    {

        string FilePath = Server.MapPath(lbdownload.Text);
        WebClient User = new WebClient();
        Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
        if (FileBuffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
            //  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + lbdownload.Text);
            //   Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", lbdownload.Text.Length.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string mRes = ex.Message;
    }
```

` i am in a lot of troubble...

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `lbdownload.Text`?

Comment: lbdownload.text  is a my file path. it contain my file path value like(images/Document/Pdffilename);

Comment: Instead of downloading the file via WebClient only to send it to the user, how about just linking the user to original file.

Comment: first  admin upload file on server then user click on button and see it on new tab....not download

Comment: if you have a any code then send me. i want ot show particular file off particuar product...